# Google sheets IFNUMBER is missing

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How do I make the following formula shorter:

return the value if it's a number, zero otherwise.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.goo.....5qLKqjw", "Data!I4:I"), IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.goo.....5qLKqjw", "Data!I4:I"), 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67541563/1527780) by [basic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12188861/basic) will work for [just a single cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67541378/google-sheets-ifnumber-is-missing#comment119382648_67541563).

This means one would have to use the `IMPORTRANGE` formula multiple times (once for each cell)

As an alternative one can use an `ArrayFormula` like

```
=INDEX(N(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.goo.....5qLKqjw", "Data!I4:I")))
```

OR

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.goo.....5qLKqjw", "Data!I4:I")^1,0))
```

Functions used:

- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`N`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093357)
- [`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=MAX(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.goo.....5qLKqjw", "Data!I4:I"),0)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this single formula work for the whole range `Data!I4:I`? Am I missing something? Doesn't Elad Ask for the whole range?

Comment: @marikamitsos Yeah, I didn't notice the whole range. This formula will work in single cell.

Comment: Please check my answer for an alternative